# Proving an inequality absolute value

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value, pointwise-convergence, triangle-inequality

If $g_n \to g$ almost everywhere, then show the following holds almost everywhere:

$$||g_k|^2 - |g - g_k|^2 - |g|^2| \leq 8|g||g - g_k|.$$

By the Triangle Inequality,

\begin{align*}
|g_k| &\leq |g| + |g - g_k| \\
|g_k|^2 &\leq |g|^2 + |g - g_k|^2 + 2|g||g - g_k| \\
|g_k|^2 - |g - g_k|^2 - |g|^2 &\leq 2|g||g - g_k| \\
|g_k|^2 - |g - g_k|^2 - |g|^2 &\leq 8|g||g - g_k|
\end{align*}

However, I'm not sure how to prove the other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand "prove other way" fully, is this what you're looking for?

\begin{align*}
|g| &\leq |g_k| + |g_k - g| \\
|g| -|g_k - g| &\leq |g_k|   \\
|g|^2 +|g_k - g|^2 - 2|g||g - g_k| &\leq |g_k|^2   \\
-2|g||g - g_k|  &\leq   |g_k|^2 - |g - g_k|^2 - |g|^2 \\
-8|g||g - g_k|  &\leq   |g_k|^2 - |g - g_k|^2 - |g|^2 \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: I noticed that $2|g||g - g_k|$ provides a better bound. Is there a way to show that $| |g_k|^2 - |g - g_k|^2 - |g|^2 | = 2|g||g - g_k|$? (provided real-valued $g_k$)

Comment: conversion of inequality to equality would indicate (1) $|g_k|^2 - |g - g_k|^2 - |g|^2  = 2|g||g - g_k|$ or (2)  $|g_k|^2 - |g - g_k|^2 - |g|^2  = -2|g||g - g_k|$. In (1) $|g_k|^2 = |g - g_k|^2 + |g|^2  +  2|g||g - g_k|= |g_k-g|^2 + |g|^2  +  2|g||g_k - g|=(|g_k-g|+|g|)^2$. Second case gives us similarly $|g_k|^2 =(|g-g_k|-|g|)^2$ - these may not hold in general? 

If the question was whether  we maintain the inequality, but reduce 8 to 2, then I would think, yes we can make the bound tighter (to 2).

Comment: Is it possible to show that $\lim_{k \to \infty} \int ||g_k(x)|^2 - |g(x) - g_k(x)|^2 - |g(x)|^2| d\lambda= 0?$ (where $g_k, g \in L^2(d\lambda)$)

Comment: @cosmicflair, since the constraints of the question are different, can i please ask you to pose it as a fresh question rather than as a comment (for the benefit of future visitors to the site)?